# Passing array values in php prepared statement not working

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

So I have a prepared statement with bind_param that works fine if I assign each piece of data to individual variables and use those variables in the bind_param statement but it doesn't work if I assign each piece of data to an array element and try to use the array elements in the bind_param statement.
Examples below:

This works:
`$insertquery->bind_param("sssssssssssssssssssss", $dbname, $dbmanacost, $dbcmc, $dbcolors, $dbtype, $dbsupertypes, $dbtypes, $dbsubtypes, $dbrarity, $dbcardtext, $dbflavortext, $dbartist, $dbnumber, $dbpower, $dbtoughness, $dblayout, $dbmultiverseid, $dbexpansion, $dbexpansioncode, $dbreleasedate, $dbversions);`

But this inserts a blank line into the database:
`$insertquery->bind_param("sssssssssssssssssssss", $db['name'], $db['manacost'], $db['cmc'], $db['colors'], $db['type'], $db['supertypes'], $db['types'], $db['subtypes'], $db['rarity'], $db['cardtext'], $db['flavortext'], $db['artist'], $db['number'], $db['power'], $db['toughness'], $db['layout'], $db['multiverseid'], $db['expansion'], $db['expansioncode'], $db['releasedate'], $db['versions']);`

The content of the variables is exactly the same in both examples.  I would like to use a single array for organizational purposes but I'm not sure why the prepared statement won't read the data.

Comment: What do you mean by *"But this inserts a blank line into the database"* ? Does it enter blank entries in all or just the one blank line? And for which one? What does var_dump'ing show? Where are the `$db`'s declared as? The question for me in that respect, is unclear.

Comment: I found the solution and will edit my question accordingly.  But in answer to your questions.  It inserts one line in the database with just the default values. Var_dump showed the correct values in the array.  Thanks anyway though.  I always appreciate how quickly people are to try to help here.

Comment: Glad you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that each time I looped through I was resetting the array by redeclaring it, as in, $db = array(...) but apparently that breaks the link from the prepared statement. I rewrote the code to blank each array element using a foreach loop and that fixed it.